# Create wrapper to check user role in App.js component routes

Tags: reactjs

I know the question is very general but I cannot find the correct way and terms to search this online to see how it can be done.
My problem is that I have an app that users log in and then a user role is added to a context element (like if the user is admin or simple user etc).
I can restrict access to the components by checking the user role and redirect. somerhing like

```
return user==="admin"?<div>...</div>: "redirect to no access component"
```

Is a way to create a wrapper that will wrap every Route in the App.js and perform this check instead.

Answer (score 1):

If its a page then you can follow the following Approach:

While attaching Routes to Router you can create custom Route component which will check the condition.
Like:

```
import { Route } from "react-router-dom";
const PrivateRouteAdmin=({path,component:Component...rest})=>{
   const user = useContext(AuthContext).userType;// any global state which you have used 
   return user==='admin'? 
      <Route path={path} {...rest} 
             render={(props)=>{
                  return <Component {...props} />
       }}/>: <Redirect to={"/"}/>
}
```

You can use it in you code as follows:

```
<BrowserRouter>
   <PrivateRouteAdmin exact path={'/protected'} component={ProtectedPage} />
</BrowserRouter>
```

If you want to apply some condition on specific page element, then you can use the approach which you are following otherwise make another component for that purpose too like:

```
    const AdminContent = ({children)=> {
      const user = useContext(AuthContext).userType;// any global state which you have used 
     return user==='admin'?children:<Redirect to={"/"}/>
}
```

and you can call the component anywhere you want like:

```
<AdminContent> <div>protected</div></AdminContent>
```

Comment: How can I pass the user data (they come from auth) to the app.js where all the routes are? I generally store the data to the context but the app.js doesn't have any connection to it. Will the protectedRoute component will be a separate component? will this be the one that will get the user data from Auth or the app.js component and will transfer it to the protectedRoute? I am confused to be honest.

Comment: Attach ContextProvider to the root element like in index.js, and then use useContext hook in app.js to access the global state i.e., from context API. and When you pass app.js as child in the contextprovider then your every component can access the context by using useContext hook. And the protectedRoute component will be seperate component. Yes you can use it for protecting your route/link. and in protectedRoute as I said you can use useContext hook too to get auth state.

Comment: Ok I am getting there. I got your logic. I have the context provider into the app and not the whole index.js. Is it ok to use the provider to the index though? Anyway, I seem to be getting the context values to the app.js now. So the next step is to create the protected component and pass the context value to it? How should I setup the app.js now? All my routes are there? How they will get through the protected component?

Comment: Now you have to create protected route component seperately and in protected route component get your user value from context and apply condition as I have mentioned in my answer above. And then in app.js simply attach your all routes to the BrowserRouter component

Answer (score 1):

- normally you should restrict the access in the router of your application.
- but to anwser the question you can create a hooks that checks if user is admin or else redirect to the no access component using react-router:

  ```
  const useCheckUserPermission = (permission) => {
      // get the user from the context
      useEffect(() => { 
         if(user === permission) // redirect to no access component
      }, [])
      return [];
  }
  ```

  then you can use it like this:

  ```
  const Component = (props) => {
     useCheckUserPermission("admin");

     return // return your component
  }
  ```

Comment: First of all thanks for replying. Secondly, how can I restrict it from the router?

Comment: @Tony I have provided the solution of router. Have a look on it.